# HTTP Get to compare to Dataverse fields

Tags: power-automate, dataverse, power-platform

HTTP Get to compare to Dataverse fields
an hour ago
I'm having trouble with my flow. I'm not sure whether to have this flow as scheduled or not at the moment. There's an external database that contains a field for a name that I need. This is collected by another piece of software. In my Dataverse table I don't have the name, but I need it.

So I'm trying to get it by using an HTTP Get request. I'm trying to compare the CustomerID from each row in the HTTP request to the CustomerID in the Dataverse table (these match up). If the CustomerIDs match up, the name is put into the Dataverse table using Update a row.

Here is what I have so far

-Dataverse list rows

-HTTP Get

-Parse JSON HTTP body

-Apply to each CustomerID from Parse JSON

-Apply to each value from list rows

-Condition - if JSON CustomerID = Dataverse CustomerID

-Update row. RowID = CurrentItem

Nothing seems to work. I've had a variety of errors.

Is there a better method to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How can I get the CustomerID and CustomerName from the HTTP response? 
Then compare the CustomerID with the Dataverse CustomerID.
If the CustomerIDs match, how do I insert the appropriate CustomerName into the Dataverse row?

I cannot filter the HTTP response for some reason. Nothing I've tried works. When trying to compare the CustomerID, I usually get an error that I cannot reference CustomerID but instead must reference the array index. When I do that, I get a full row in response instead of just the CustomerID field.